# CSS file based on the domain through which the application was accessed

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, master-pages

I have a asp.net MVC application. This application is going to be called from different  domain names. I need to apply the CSS file to the application based on the domain it was called from. Is there a way I can  do this on the master page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can switch between different domains using java script on master page.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  if(document.domain == "localhost")
  {
      //alert(document.domain);
      $("link[media='screen']").attr("href", "<%= AppHelper.CssUrl("Green_Blue.css") %>");
  }

  if(document.domain == "mycomputer")
  {
      //alert(document.domain);
      $("link[media='screen']").attr("href", "<%= AppHelper.CssUrl("Blue_Peach.css") %>");
  }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head; In the controller you could use Request.Url.Authority to obtain the domain.  Then set the viewdata to the path of your style sheet depending on the domain.

Then in your view do something like this;

```
<link href="<%= "" + ViewData[Namespace.StyleSheetKey] %>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: here is an article to help with passing data to the master page http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2008/08/12/asp-net-mvc-tip-31-passing-data-to-master-pages-and-user-controls.aspx